IntegrityError when trying to add a new user in Flask with SQLAlchemy
I'm working on a Flask application where I have a form to allow users to input their username and password. Once submitted, the user's information should be displayed on another webpage along with all previously entered users.
The issue I’m encountering is that the first time I submit the form, it works perfectly. However, when I attempt to add another user, I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.username
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Joey.O', 'valiant56@outlook.com')]

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///project.db'
db.init_app(app)

from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column

class User(db.Model):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    email: Mapped[str]

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home Page')

@app.route('/list')
def user_list():
    users = db.session.execute(db.select(User).order_by(User.username)).scalars()
    return render_template('user_list.html', title='User List', users=users)

@app.route('/create_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(
            username=request.form['username'],
            email=request.form['email'],
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user_list', id=user.id))
        
    return render_template('create_user.html', title='Create User')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


You defined the username field in the user database to be unique, but then you tried to add a username that already existed.

What exactly is your question about this? Why do you expect that you shouldn't get the IntegrityError?

The first time i submitted the users info. It went well. I made a link to go back to create_user so as i attempt submitting another users info it shows that error. Im asking on how it can be fixed.

Im asking on how it can be fixed When you create more users, make sure the usernames are different.

According to your model, the username is a unique field, which prevents duplicate values from being stored in the database. Therefore, the best approach would be to check if a user with the same username already exists before attempting to add a new one. If a duplicate is found, return a 400 error.
You can achieve it by adding an additional check to the method:
@app.route('/create_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usersname = request.form['username']

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user:
            abort(400, 'User with provided username already exists')

        user = User(
            username=request.form['username'],
            email=request.form['email'],
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user_list', id=user.id))
        
    return render_template('create_user.html', title='Create User')

This way you will handle situation when you try to add a user with a duplicate username

The IntegrityError is triggered due to the db.create_all() statement running on the second or subsequent time. To solve this, you can add db.drop_all() statement to drop all tables before creating and inserting the data again.
with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

